# Error al meter un WHILE en una plantilla de Django

Tags: python, django, while

Necesito implementar un WHILE en una plantilla HTML, este es mi código:

```
        {% while hora < 2001: %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"><a onclick="miFuncion()">{{hora}}</th>
          {{hora = hora + 30}}
        </tr>
        {% end while %}
```

El problema es que Django me da este error:

invalid block tag on line 14: 'while'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Alguien me podría ayudar por favor? seguro que es una tontería pero no lo veo. Gracis

Comment: Django no tiene el tag de `while`. Te recomiendo que pases la lista al template en el contexto y usar un `for` sobre la lista ya que puede ser computada en la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django no tiene el filter tag 'while'.

Si lo que quieres es iterar una lista, te recomiendo hacer el filtro que necesitas en views.py mandarla al template por contexto. Lo unico que te quedaria es hacer un 'for' en el template, que es un filter tag que si existe.

Si lo que estas buscando hacer es renderizar el HTML si `hora` es menor a 2001, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
{% if hora < 2001 %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><a onclick="miFuncion()">{{hora}}</th>
      {{hora = hora + 30}}
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```